# How to detect char buffer encoding?

Tags: c, encoding, character-encoding, detection

Is there any free open-source library to auto-detect encoding of an arbitrary `char*` buffer?

For example, in python there is a module named [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet), that does the same job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it's really difficult to say unless the `char* buffer` has some sort header info. Interesting...

Comment: @SparKot Yes, it is difficult, but there is a module in python, named chardet, that somehow does the job

Comment: The library says its "guessing". To guess obviously it would need a set of encoding information of each type. If you know how each type of encoded string is represented, analysing another PARTIAL value won't be too hard. Check out Bayesian Networks or Probabilistic search.

Comment: Try [enca](http://gitorious.org/enca).

Comment: At best one can guess.  In some cases the guess would be pretty certain to be accurate, in other cases not.

Answer (score 1):

If [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is present then you can use the specific sequences that must be at the beginning of the stream to find the encoding used.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but it does not work for 8-bit encodings like cp1251 :(

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing in C but perl has a library [Encode-Detect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encode-Detect/). Perhaps, looking at how they implemented could help.